# How to use OpenAIClient to provide a a story that the bot should use for the responses?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

I am trying to use [OpenAIClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.openaiclient?view=azure-dotnet-preview) to interact with a ChatGPT model hosted on Azure.

I am looking for a way to guide the AI model by giving it a small story including some key information that it should be using when completing the prompts.

For example, I want to tell the AI model, given this context answer the prompts that user is requesting.

Here is what I tried to do

```
var client = new OpenAIClient(..., ...);


var response = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync("...",
     new ChatCompletionsOptions(new List<ChatMessage>
         {
             new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, "Some text to guide the AI model in the response"),
             new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "What is your name and age?"),
         }));
```

I don't know how to tell the AI model key info, like it's name, age, and other info the user may be prompting.

How can I identify a short story/context where the AI model can then use to answer the prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a short story or context for the AI model to use when answering prompts, you can utilize the **system message** in the `ChatCompletionsOptions` when using the `OpenAIClient`.

The system message can include key information, personality traits, and instructions for the AI model.

Below is sample code snippet:

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;
using static System.Environment;

string endpoint = "";
string key = "";

// Enter the deployment name you chose when you deployed the model.
//string engine = "deploymentname1";

OpenAIClient client = new(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(key));
var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
{
    Messages =
    {
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, "You are a helpful assistant. Your name is Mike and your age is 20"),
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "Can you help me?"),
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, "Sure, my name is Mike and age is 20."),
        new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "What is your name and age?"),
    }
};
Response<StreamingChatCompletions> response = await client.GetChatCompletionsStreamingAsync(
    deploymentOrModelName: "deploymentname1",
    chatCompletionsOptions);
using StreamingChatCompletions streamingChatCompletions = response.Value;

await foreach (StreamingChatChoice choice in streamingChatCompletions.GetChoicesStreaming())
{
    await foreach (ChatMessage message in choice.GetMessageStreaming())
    {
        Console.Write(message.Content);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

You can modify the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! What is the different between `System` role and `Assistant` int his case?

Comment: The system message is included at the beginning of the array and provides the initial instructions to the model and Assistant is this response from the based on the previous chat message from user.